# Word problem - How many times was the player at bat during the entire season?

Tags: problem-solving, average, word-problem

Its the first time I am asking a question on a forum. I have been self-studying math for a month and now am stuck in word problem chapter. I searched a lot for a solution manual, but I didn't find any.

Book: College Algebra by M.A. Munem

*How to solve the question below?*

Help will be appreciated.

**QUESTION:**

In baseball, a player’s batting average is found by dividing the number of safe hits by the number of times at bat. A certain player got $50$ safe hits in his first $200$ times at bat in the baseball season. He hits $0.300$ for the rest of the season and finishes with a season average of $0.280$. How many times was the player at bat during the entire season?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let n be the total number of times at bat for the season.  Since the player's batting average was 0.280 he had a total of 0.280n hits for the entire season. Since his average "for the rest of the season", when he had n- 200 at bats, was 0.300, he had 0.300(n- 200) hits in that period.  He got 50 hits in those 200 at bats so he had a total of 50+ 0.300(n- 200)= 0.280n for the season.  0.3n- 60= .28n.  Solve that equation for n.

Comment: Thank you for help.